# system "ssh ..." not working well {ruby}

Tags: ruby, ssh

I'm new to ruby and having a strange issue with command `system "command`" 
this is the lines ofc code I want to run

```
pd = publicDomain

puts "launching Apache server in PD :#{pd}"

system  "scp -i #{AWS_CON['SSH_Key']} -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no #{AWS_CON['bash_sh']} ec2-user@#{pd}:./bash.sh"
sleep 3
system "ssh -tt -i #{AWS_CON['SSH_Key']} -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ec2-user@#{pd} \"sudo bash ./bash.sh\"
```

when `AWS_CON` is `.yml` a file to store configurations

when i run it in script I get error

```
launching Apache server in PD :ec2-xx-xxx-xx-xx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
ssh: connect to host ec2-xx-xxx-xx-xx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com port 22: Connection refused
lost connection
ssh: connect to host ec2-xx-xxx-xx-xx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com port 22: Connection refused
```

but I run it using **pry** it runs fine .
what can be the cause of it ?

Comment: It looks like the service is down. Are you sure you're connecting to the same host(s) in both cases?

Comment: yes, I checkde and re-checked